# Чи є семантична різниця між словами "асоціація", "конгрес", "ліга", "обєднання", "союз", "спілка", "товариство", "федерація"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, legal-terms

**Контекст** — об'єднання людей з метою захисту або просування своїх політичних або соціальних інтересів.

У мережі є приклади використання усіх цих слів:

- [**Асоціація** правників України](http://uba.ua/)
- **Конґрес** Українців Америки
- Світовий **Конґрес** Українців
- [**Ліга** студентів](http://ligauba.org.ua/)
- **Об'єднання** «Майдан»
- **Об'єднання** Страховиків
- [**Союз** Українок](http://su.org.ua/)
- [**Союз** Українців Британії](http://www.ukrainiansintheuk.info/ukr/03/sub-u.htm)
- [**Спілка** Української Молоді](http://cym.org/ua/)
- [**Спілка** Політв'язнів України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8)
- але і [Всеукраїнське **товариство** політичних в'язнів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%96_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85)
- Наукове **Товариство** iм. Шевченка
- **Товариство** Об'єднаних Слов'ян
- [**Федерація** проф**спілок** України](http://www.fpsu.org.ua)

Чи є принципова семантична різниця між цими словами у вищезазначеному контексті?

Comment: IMHO є й третє значення слова "конгрес". Я маю на увазі "Конгрес Українських Націоналістів", який не є ажніяк постійним з'їздом.

Comment: @AlexeyDobrovolsky Цитую частину своєї відповіді."У наведених автором питання прикладах усі слова, значення яких спонукало до запитання, входять саме до назв організацій (чи то окреме товариство, чи то об’єднання), незалежно від організаційно-правової форми, а в назву, зрозуміло, можна записати будь-що, жодних обмежень (хоч "Міжгалактичне Утворення") :)" Це саме стосуєтья "Конгресу українських націоналістів". В назву можна додати все, що завгодно. Але це не додає самому слову "конгрес" нового значення на підставі вживання у власній назві, а не відповідно до словника.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Відповідаючи на це питання, слід, на мій погляд, розглядати два аспекти: ***мовний*** і ***юридичний***.

Щодо першого звертаємося до [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/) (цитуємо тільки контекстуальні значення):

**[ТОВАРИ́СТВО](http://sum.in.ua/s/tovarystvo)**, а, сер. 5. Організація, об'єднання людей, які ставлять перед собою спільні завдання, мету, програму дій і відповідно діють для їх виконання, здійснення.

**[СПІ́ЛКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/spilka)**, и, жін. 2. Об'єднання людей, пов'язаних спільними умовами життя, спільною метою; товариство.

**[ОБ'Є́ДНАННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ob.jednannja)**, я, сер. 2. Організація людей на основі спільності мети, завдань; спілка.

**[АСОЦІА́ЦІЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/asociacija)**, ї, жін. 1. Добровільне об'єднання осіб або організацій для досягнення спільної господарської, політичної, культурної чи якої-небудь іншої мети; товариство, спілка.

**[ЛІГА](http://sum.in.ua/s/ligha)** 1, и, жін. Об'єднання окремих осіб, організацій, держав; асоціація (у 1 знач.).

**[СОЮ́З](http://sum.in.ua/s/sojuz)**, у, чол. 2. Об'єднання груп людей, організацій, держав для яких-небудь спільних дій, спільної мети.

**[ФЕДЕРА́ЦІЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/federacija)**, ї, жін. 1. Державне об'єднання, що складається з кількох держав; об'єднання племен, родів і т. ін. із спільною верховною владою; створення, організація такого об'єднання.
2. Спілка товариств, організацій і т. ін.

**[КОНГРЕ́С](http://sum.in.ua/s/konghres)**, у, чол. 1. З'їзд, нарада з широким представництвом, переважно міжнародного характеру.
2. Законодавчий орган (парламент) у США та більшості латиноамериканських країн.

Таким чином, можна зробити **Висновок**, що **ТОВАРИСТВО**, **СПІЛКА** – синоніми в тому розумінні, що зазвичай це, так би мовити, ***єднання в одну неподільну організацію***.

В той же час **АСОЦІАЦІЯ**, **ЛІГА**, **СОЮЗ**, **ФЕДЕРАЦІЯ** (у запитуваному контексті) – також певним чином синоніми, але це ***об’єднання двох або більше незалежних*** (або відносно незалежних) ***організацій***.

Щодо самого **ОБ’ЄДНАННЯ** ситуація трошки заплутаніша, оскільки тлумачення відповідно до СУМ відрізняється від визначення як юридичного терміна. (Я для себе зробила висновок, що коли об'єднання людей в одну організацію, то тоді синонім до **ТОВАРИСТВО**, **СПІЛКА**, коли ж мається на увазі об'єднання кількох різних організацій, то синонім до **АСОЦІАЦІЯ**, **ЛІГА**, **СОЮЗ**, **ФЕДЕРАЦІЯ**).

**КОНГРЕС** випадає з цих синонімічних рядів, оскільки має всього два значення, кожне з яких поза контекстом (або тимчасове зібрання (з’їзд, нарада), або законодавчий орган в окремих країнах).

---

Аналіз в юридичній площині (розглядаємо українське законодавство) частково підтверджує наведений вище висновок і свідчить про таке.

[**ГОСПОДАРСЬКИЙ КОДЕКС УКРАЇНИ**](http://zakon0.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/436-15)

> **Глава 12**
>
> **ОБ'ЄДНАННЯ ПІДПРИЄМСТВ**
>
> **Стаття 118. Поняття об'єднання підприємств**
>
> 1. **Об'єднанням підприємств** є господарська організація, утворена у складі ***двох або більше підприємств*** з метою координації їх
>    виробничої, наукової та іншої діяльності для вирішення спільних
>    економічних та соціальних завдань.
>
> <...>
>
> **Стаття 120. Організаційно-правові форми об'єднань підприємств**
>
> 1. Господарські об'єднання утворюються як **асоціації**, **корпорації**, **консорціуми**, **концерни**, **інші** об'єднання підприємств, передбачені законом.
> 2. **Асоціація** - договірне об'єднання, створене з метою постійної координації господарської діяльності підприємств, що об'єдналися,
>    шляхом централізації однієї або кількох виробничих та управлінських
>    функцій, розвитку спеціалізації і кооперації виробництва, організації
>    спільних виробництв на основі об'єднання учасниками фінансових та
>    матеріальних ресурсів для задоволення переважно господарських потреб
>    учасників асоціації. У статуті асоціації повинно бути зазначено, що
>    вона є господарською асоціацією. Асоціація не має права втручатися у
>    господарську діяльність підприємств - учасників асоціації. За рішенням
>    учасників асоціація може бути уповноважена представляти їх інтереси у
>    відносинах з органами влади, іншими підприємствами та організаціями.
> 3. **Корпорацією** визнається договірне об'єднання, створене на основі поєднання виробничих, наукових і комерційних інтересів підприємств, що
>    об'єдналися, з делегуванням ними окремих повноважень централізованого
>    регулювання діяльності кожного з учасників органам управління
>    корпорації.
> 4. **Консорціум** - тимчасове статутне об'єднання підприємств для досягнення його учасниками певної спільної господарської мети
>    (реалізації цільових програм, науково-технічних, будівельних проектів
>    тощо). Консорціум використовує кошти, якими його наділяють учасники,
>    централізовані ресурси, виділені на фінансування відповідної програми,
>    а також кошти, що надходять з інших джерел, в порядку, визначеному
>    його статутом. У разі досягнення мети його створення консорціум
>    припиняє свою діяльність.
> 5. **Концерном** визнається статутне об'єднання підприємств, а також інших організацій, на основі їх фінансової залежності від одного або
>    групи учасників об'єднання, з централізацією функцій
>    науково-технічного і виробничого розвитку, інвестиційної, фінансової,
>    зовнішньоекономічної та іншої діяльності. Учасники концерну наділяють
>    його частиною своїх повноважень, у тому числі правом представляти їх
>    інтереси у відносинах з органами влади, іншими підприємствами та
>    організаціями. Учасники концерну не можуть бути одночасно учасниками
>    іншого концерну.
> 6. Державні і комунальні господарські об'єднання утворюються переважно у формі корпорації або концерну, незалежно від найменування об'єднання
>    (комбінат, трест тощо).

**[ЦИВІЛЬНИЙ КОДЕКС УКРАЇНИ](http://zakon0.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/435-15)**

> **Стаття 83. Організаційно-правові форми юридичних осіб**
>
> 1. **Юридичні особи можуть створюватися у формі товариств, установ та в інших формах, встановлених законом**.
> 2. **Товариством** є організація, створена шляхом об'єднання осіб (учасників), які мають право участі у цьому товаристві. Товариство
>    може бути створено однією особою, якщо інше не встановлено законом.
>
> Товариства поділяються на підприємницькі та непідприємницькі.

**[ЗАКОН УКРАЇНИ «Про господарські товариства»](http://zakon0.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/1576-12)**

> **Розділ I ЗАГАЛЬНІ ПОЛОЖЕННЯ**
>
> **Стаття 1. Господарські товариства**
>
> Господарським товариством є юридична особа, статутний (складений)
> капітал якої поділений на частки між учасниками.
>
> Господарськими товариствами цим Законом визнаються підприємства,
> установи, організації,  створені на засадах угоди юридичними особами і
> громадянами шляхом об'єднання їх майна та підприємницької діяльності з
> метою одержання прибутку.   До господарських товариств належать:
> акціонерні товариства, товариства з обмеженою відповідальністю,
> товариства з додатковою відповідальністю, повні товариства, командитні
> товариства.

---

**У наведених автором питання прикладах усі слова, значення яких спонукало до запитання, входять саме до назв організацій (чи то окреме товариство, чи то об’єднання), незалежно від організаційно-правової форми, а в назву, зрозуміло, можна записати будь-що, жодних обмежень (хоч *"Міжгалактичне Утворення"*)** :)